# Using Babel in a Pyramid Project with Jinja2

Tags: python, jinja2, pyramid, python-babel

I have a Pyramid project that uses Jinja2. I am trying to use Babel by adding the following to the setup.py

```
message_extractors = { '.': [
            ('**.py', 'python', None ),
            ('static/**', 'ignore', None),
            ('resources/**', 'ignore', None),
            ('climmob3/templates/**.html', 'jinja2', None),
            ('FlatLab/**', 'ignore', None),
            ]},
```

And I have a setup.cfg file with

```
[compile_catalog]
directory = climmob3/locale
domain = climmob3
statistics = true

[extract_messages]
add_comments = TRANSLATORS:
output_file = climmob3/locale/climmob3.pot
width = 80

[init_catalog]
domain = climmob3
input_file = climmob3/locale/climmob3.pot
output_dir = climmob3/locale

[update_catalog]
domain = climmob3
input_file = climmob3/locale/climmob3.pot
output_dir = climmob3/locale
previous = true
```

However when I run

> python setup.py extract_messages

I can see tha it tries to extract the messages from the template files (.html) but it does not recognizes neither _ or {% trans %} so the .pot file is empty

Do I need to do anything extra?

Answer (score 0):

Since the output is verboese by default you should see any .html files that it passed through and recognized. If none then the paths set in `message_extractors` are not matching the structure. The `python setup.py extract_messages` command is relative so `climmob3/templates/**.html` for example should be in the same folder you run the command.